# apache cxf: multiple endpoints or multiple CXFServlet servlets?

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I have implemented an Apache CXF Webservice with multiple endpoints.

I have successfully deployed the webservice.

The problem I have is all the endpoints WSDL appear in the same servlet URL.

Can I  have two servlets of type `org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet` in the same `web.xml` and have each servlet serve one endpoint so that I the following ? ...

- Endpoint 1 at http:/localhost/app/**endpoint1**

and

- Endpoint 2 at http:/localhost/app/**endpoint2**

Answer (score 2):

What is the motivation for using 2 CXFServlets?  CXF supports multiple endpoints per servlet instance.

Can be configured numerous ways.  One example:

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="endpoint1" 
  implementor="#service1Impl" 
  address="/endpoint1">...</jaxws:endpoint>

<jaxws:endpoint id="endpoint2" 
  implementor="#service2Impl" 
  address="/endpoint2">...</jaxws:endpoint>
```

..where service1Impl and service2Impl are beans implementing your service interfaces.

Comment: but when in the /endpoint1 url, i cant see the method from /endpoint2

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide more detail about your deployment?  Jetty?  Tomcat?  Something else?

From the [docs](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/servlet-transport.html), it looks like it's as simple as

```
Endpoint.publish("/service1", new ServiceOneImpl());
Endpoint.publish("/service2", new ServiceTwoImpl());
```

But I have not tried that myself.